Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0
I’m using quasar to build an android project, when I input 'quasar d -m cordova -T android' in cmd to debug the project, I got these following information.It seems like my android studio's gradle vertion and my project jdk version have something wrong? Need help! Thanks a lot :)
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'xxxx Management System'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: E:\xxxx\xxxx\templates\src-cordova\platforms\android\tools\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug

 App · Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1
 App · Updated Cordova config.xml
 App · ⚠️  [FAIL] Cordova CLI has failed

I tried to replace my studio's gradle and jdk, but it didn't work.

This question is similar to: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

hey, did you find a solution for this? getting the same error on my first day with quasar

Sorry, I completely forget how I solve the problem...But finaly my coworker and I solve this problem in a different way. We did following thing:


Delete all project and reload the first pure version project.     2.Follow the documents of the quasar project to configure your android environments   3. Make sure your android version and gradle version and etc. are not conflicted.

